# Most universally importable e-mail file format with attachment support?

Tags: php, email, outlook, email-attachments, eml

I am in the process of creating a webmail export script in PHP. The reason we want to export the e-mails is that we intend to retire the webmail functionality from our site, and we want our users to have access to an archive of their mail.

I have created a script that successfully exports a user's e-mail in the .eml file format, and it works great if the files are imported into Mozilla Thunderbird or Windows Live mail. Microsoft Outlook, however, does not handle the attachments correctly. In Outlook 2007 an attached spreadsheet is not even recognized or displayed at all.

I found [this information](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/354), which indicates that older versions of Outlook need to be up to date for .eml files to be recognized properly, but the aforementioned results are achieved when using an up to date Windows 7 PC.

My question: 
Is there a better format for e-mail archive files that will work in Outlook as well as the other most used e-mail software/services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook should be able to handle EML files just fine. What is the actual MIME header of the MIME part that Outlook cannot handle?

You can also use MSG file format, but it is as binary as it gets, and only Outlook can understand it.

Comment: The mime type is 'application/vnd.openxmlformats' . [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9lj4bfTBF25a2dYYVRhdjg1bnc/view?usp=sharing) is a downloadable .eml file that my script generated.

Comment: Is an ENML file the same as an .eml file?

Comment: Yes, sorry, thick fingers :-) I can open the EML file in Outlook from your web site just fine.

Comment: Do you see the XLSX attachment when you open the EML file in Outlook? I still don't see the excel attachment on my side. I guess the problem might just be related to my specific PC or software combination...

Comment: I do see it,, but the message body looks like a separate attachment.

Comment: I have confirmed that my install of Outlook is the main problem by using Thunderbird to create an email equivalent to the file I attached in my first comment, and then exporting it as EML. I then dragged the file into Outlook, and lo and behold, the same issue. I guess I can now go forward from here... Thanks for your input @dmitry, I appreciate it :-)

Comment: to come back to the the original question, would you say the EML file format is indeed the most universally importable e-mail file format with attachment support? If so, I think it should be added to your answer.

Comment: Its is, EML (MIME really) is the language of SMTP, POP3, and IMAP4.

Comment: My edit got rejected... Oh well, you can add it to your answer if you want,